# Toggle between css states Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, text, input

I have a bootstrap input here:

```
<div class="form-group input-group has-warning col-lg-2" id="state">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name='user' id="inputWarning" width='60' autofocus maxlength=20 required onblur="check()">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="loadingCheck">✔</span>
</div>
```

I want to change its validation upon an ajax response. Is it possible?

Comment: can you explain a bit more on what your trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can using [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group input-group has-warning col-lg-2" id="state">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name='user' id="inputWarning" width='60' autofocus maxlength=20 required onblur="check()">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="loadingCheck"></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div').removeClass('has-warning');
   $('div').addClass('has-success');
});
```

***UPDATE***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = $('div');
    if(a.hasClass('has-warning') || a.hasClass('has-error')){
       a.removeClass('has-warning');
       a.removeClass('has-error'); 
       a.addClass('has-success');
    }
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/SvAx9/1/)**

Comment: One more question. I want to delete the has class an apply an other class. I don't know if its has-warning or has-error etc.. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$( "#state" ).removeClass( "has-warning" )` on the check() AJAX response.

Comment: And how can I apply the has-success class on it?